# Database connection simplified - Is this right?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to teach myself c#, and have found various examples on connecting to a MSSQL database.  What I've done seems to be the simplest way to do it, but still seems overly complicated.

Is there a better way?

here's my code:

```
static void dbcon()
{
    List<int> familyID = new List<int>();
    String connString = "Server=[myServer]\\[myInstance];Database=[dbName];User Id=[userID};Password=[password];";
    using (var sqlconn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        using (var cmd = sqlconn.CreateCommand())
        {
            try
            {
                sqlconn.Open();
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT id FROM family";
                using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        familyID.Add(Convert.ToInt32(reader["id"].ToString()));
                    }
                }
                foreach (int tempy in familyID)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("id: " + tempy);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }                   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless you can do something more useful in your `catch` clause, I'd recommend removing it. It's usually far better to let the exception propagate up to the top level - especially for a general `Exception`, which could be anything at this point. If you don't `catch` it, then a) your process will terminate (which is good, because you *don't know* what error occurred), and b) the helpers should show a full stack trace for you (so you can see where the error originated, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fine for an app that only runs one sql statement, but you wouldn't want to use all that code every time you wanted new data.

What you want to do is separate the code that creates the connection, from the code that gets and runs the sql, from the code that deals with the results.

This way, the connection code (and possibly the data display code) can be written once and called each time you want to execute different sql, and you only have to concentrate on how to write the code that gets the data you want.

hth

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  Not to go off topic now, but:
in your example, do you leave the database connection open "permanently" for the whole runtime?  I think my understanding of the "USING()" with the garbage collection isn't good enough.

I am thinking that the command and reader had to be encapsulated within the using(connection) so the connection is available to the others.

Comment: Shut down the connection, especially if it will take time between getting and updating the data.  Normally you'd open the connection, grab the data and shut down the connection.  Then open another connection, insert/update data with whatever changes you've made and shut it down again.  This way other users can use the database concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

**Details:** First of all welcome to Stackoverflow. Just a few tips below

Having your connection string hard coded like that is bad practice. You should ALWAYS have it in your App.config (or Web.config if it is a web application). The reason is because if you have it hard coded and your boss ask you to change the Applications Database connection string you will need to recompile the entire application. If you have it in a App.config file you just need to change it (open it up with notepad) and save it.

Example on how to add it to the app.config

```
<configuration>
   <connectionStrings>
         <add name="myConnectionString" 
           connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=MySQLServerDB; 
           Integrated Security=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
   </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Then to access it in your code (You will need to add a reference to System.Configuration as well as add using System.Configuration;)

```
string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

In regards to your other code I would change your exception catching to include the Sql Exception first and then fall back to any other exceptions.

```
  catch (SqlException ex)
  {
      // Handle the Sql Exception code
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
      // Handle the Normal Exception code
  }
```

Comment: Um, They're using `using` statements - the connections will get closed automatically (because `using` is effectively a `try/finally` anyway, with `Dispose()` called in the `finally` block, and for connections, `Close()` and `Dispose()` are synonymous)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, Thanks for picking that up! I will change my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

The example contained in the docs for [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.aspx) is quite easy to follow and understand as an alternative way.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder =
  new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
builder["Data Source"] = "(local)";
builder["integrated Security"] = true;
builder["Initial Catalog"] = "AdventureWorks;NewValue=Bad";
Console.WriteLine(builder.ConnectionString);
```

**Edit:**

Actually, the example I copied above shows you how the SqlConnectionStringBuilder class handles an "...invalid value in a safe manner". Whoops. At least it gives you an idea of how it works.

For more info on the various methods of obtaining, storing and constructing your connection string within ADO.NET, look at the [MSDN documentation on Connection Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254978%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)